# VIEWS in MySQL Workbench always return (0) row(s)

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-workbench

```
drop database if exists RentaHouse;
create database RentaHouse;

use RentaHouse;

create table Staff(
staffNo char(5) not null primary key,
fName varchar(15),
lName varchar(15),
position varchar(15),
dob date,
salary decimal (7,2) unsigned
);

create table PropertyForRent(
propertyNo char(5) primary key,
street varchar(35) not null,
city varchar(15) not null,
pcode varchar(10),
type varchar(20) not null,
rooms tinyint unsigned not null,
rent decimal (6,2) unsigned,
staffNo char(5)
);

ALTER TABLE PropertyForRent
    ADD CONSTRAINT whatever foreign key(staffNo) references Staff (staffNo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


insert into staff values
('s1234','Mary','Jones', 'Sales', '1975-12-22',45000),
('s1834','Pat','Roche', 'IT', '1972-09-13',42000),
('s1998','Michael','Brown', 'Sales', '1980-12-09',43500);

insert into propertyForRent values
('p3296','21 Ash Street','Tramore','WD34-543', 'Bungalow',4,1200,'s1234'),
('p3299','William Street','Dungarvan','WD99-088', 'Terrace',3,1050,'s1234'),
('p3344','9 Mary Street','New Ross','WX99-044', 'Terrace',3,800,'s1998'),
('p3356','21 Mary Street','New Ross','WX99-076', '2 Storey',4,1100,null);



/*doesn't work!*/
CREATE VIEW anyView AS 
    select * from Staff;

/*work!*/
select * from Staff;

/*work!*/
select street, city, type, rent, concat(fName, lName) as 'Name' from 
PropertyForRent join Staff on PropertyForRent.staffNo = Staff.staffNo  where city = 'New Ross' order by rent;

/*doesn't work!*/
CREATE VIEW myView AS 
select street, city, type, rent, concat(fName, lName) as 'Name' from 
PropertyForRent join Staff on PropertyForRent.staffNo = Staff.staffNo  where city = 'New Ross' order by rent;
```

all the views are not returning any result!
I am using "sakila" as a default schema using MySQL Workbench 6.3.8.

I've been 2 days searching online for a solution but I think it's time to ask who have expertise please.

P.S views are not working for any database I create not only for this schema!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using mysql command line? Try to use the schema (select * from RentaHouse.anyView;). I haven't found any problem at all. Take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e9ca1/2

Comment: select * from RentaHouse.anyView; If it works, the problem is your workbench is creating the view in another database. Try to set the default database by clicking at RentaHouse database and setting it as a Defaulf Database. The default database should be in bold.

Comment: You have created same name multiple views. second thing is you haven't write select query to show the view data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW anyView1 AS  select * from Staff;

then fetch data
select * from anyView1;


CREATE VIEW myViewss AS 
select street, city, type, rent, concat(fName, lName) as 'Name' from 
PropertyForRent join Staff on PropertyForRent.staffNo = Staff.staffNo            where city = 'New Ross' order by rent;


 select * from myViewss;
```